# Is crorrect and natural to say "don't do something nearly as much as someone"?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Could you tell me if it is crorrect and natural to say *don't do something nearly as someone*? For example:

> Sara doesn't eat **nearly** as much sugar as you.

What I'm trying to say that Sara eats a lot less sugar that the person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could you tell me if it is correct and natural to say don't do
> something nearly as someone?

No. You have omitted "much"

"... don't do something nearly *as much as* someone" is correct.

> For example:
>
> Sara doesn't eat nearly as much sugar as you.

Yes. That is correct.